# How detect subview is Button in UIHostingController - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uihostingcontroller

I need to get a button from the SwiftUI view that is wrapped in `UIHostingController`. In UIKit we simply could check the type in this way:

```
for (id subview in subviews) {
   if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
      //do code for UIKit 
   }
}
```

How should handle this for the SwiftUI view that added as a view in UIViewController?

Comment: That's not very good approach. Would you explain where do you need that? And show your code. I believe there is also direct way to work with your controls, if needed.

Comment: It seems a better way to handle the view indirectly by handling the data in SwiftUI